# How to use tinylog in Eclipse plugin

Tags: eclipse, plugins, tinylog

I am writing an Eclipse plugin and want to use tinylog in my plugin code. I tried this:

1). modified Eclipse config file (eclipse.ini) to add this line:
`-Dtinylog.configuration=C:\eclipse-cpp-2018-09-win32-x86_64\eclipse\tinylog.properties`

2). content of tinylog.properties:

```
writer          = file
writer.level    = debug              
writer.file     = C:\eclipse-cpp-2018-09-win32-x86_64\eclipse\log.txt
writer.charset  = UTF-8             
writer.append   = true 
writer.buffered = true
```

After launching Eclipse and run my plugin, I couldn't see log.txt

BTW, my tinylog version is of 1.3.6

Comment: The eclipse.ini is only used by plug-ins installed in your main Eclipse installation - have you done that? Or are all you testing the plug-in using 'Run As > Eclipse Application' which starts a separate Eclipse with a separate ini file.

Comment: I installed my plugin under eclipse's dropins folder so that the plugin looks like a thirdparty one. then I restarted Eclipse.

Comment: keen to hear any suggestion.

Comment: I tried to put my plugin under plugins folder, the result is the same.

Comment: Hope some Eclipse ans Eclipse plugin and tinylog experts can give some suggestions

Comment: I raised similar discussion/help in Eclipse forum. https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php?t=rview&goto=1826693#msg_1826693 If u checked the attached files there, you can see Eclipse can get tinylog.configuration value correctly.

Comment: Could you provide a minimal example plugin as GitHub project to reproduce your issue?

Comment: I'd like to upload my sample project. Where can I put it? I modify src from https://github.com/umlet/umlet and followed https://www.umlet.com/faq.htm steps: How to start UMLet as Eclipse-Plugin?

Download the "com.umlet.plugin*.jar" file and copy it to Eclipse's plugin directory. to test.

Comment: I sent to Martin's email box and I use NetBeans to build

Comment: forgot to mention that you may need to run the plugin for Eclipse CDT (C++) build

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using tinylog 1 with a configuration for tinylog 2. The correct configuration for tinylog 1.3.6 would be:

```
tinylog.writer          = file
tinylog.writer.level    = debug  
tinylog.writer.filename = C:\eclipse-cpp-2018-09-win32-x86_64\eclipse\log.txt
tinylog.writer.buffered = true
tinylog.writer.append   = true
```

In tinylog 1.3.6, the charset cannot be defined in the configuration. Instead, tinylog 1 will use the default charset for your system. The manual for tinylog 1 can be found here: https://tinylog.org/v1/configuration

**Update:** I just uploaded a working minimal example project on GitHub: https://github.com/pmwmedia/tinylog-eclipse-plugin-example. It contains an Eclipse plug-in that uses tinylog 1.3.6 as logging framework.

Comment: I used your configuration with tinylog.writer.buffered = false. <br/>  
It's improving that log file was created but it was empty. the logging stmt is so simple and easy to use, I couldn't figure out where the problem it could be in my code.  Initially buffered was set to TRUE and later to be FALSE. log file always empty.  <br/>   Where did you test your example? Eclipse Java version or Eclipse CDT version. Hope your example run well in Eclipse CDT version as well.

Comment: how to build your example? I got this error:  <br/> Failed to load p2 metadata repository from location http://download.eclipse.org/releases/2020-03: No repository found at http://download.eclipse.org/releases/2020-03

Comment: I changed to tinylog version 2.1.1 and now it's working. thanks   Martin

Comment: I set buffered FALSE but I have to quit Eclipse before I can see log file being populated. I raised the question in Eclipse forum.